# Password policy not working on root user on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, configuration

*/etc/pam.d/common-password*

```bsh
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password    requisite           pam_pwquality.so retry=3 minlen=10 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 maxrepeat=3 reject_username difok=7 enforce_for_root
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass yescrypt
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
```

*/etc/login.defs*

```bsh
#
PASS_MAX_DAYS   30
PASS_MIN_DAYS   2
PASS_WARN_AGE   7
#
```

**
[image]

I'm very new to this subject, I would appreciate if you explain the basic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Use command `chage` with parameter `-m` to change the minimum number of days, `-M` to change the maximum number of days and appropriate *user_name*.

Eg:

```
chage -m 7 -M 30 root
```

to change password settings for root